# Postgres: must appear in the GROUP BY while I am using an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

When I run the sql as below I receive the following error message:

> column `subQuery.numbers` must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause or be used in an aggregate function**"

I don't understand why this error comes out while I'm using aggregate functions `sum` and `count` in `left join` with an alias.

I think that the parent query doesn't recognize the subquery with its alias("subQuery").

I'm trying to find the solution but i didn't find other cases like me.
Could you please explain me why this error comes out while aggregate function used?

```
select to_char(customer1.date_time, 'MM-dd') as DateTime, 
(case when subQuery.numbers is null then 0 else subQuery.numbers end) as "2019-numbers", 
(case when subQuery.amount is null then 0 else subQuery.amount end) as "2019-amount"
from customer_table customer1
left join (
select to_char(customer2.date_time, 'MM-dd') as DateTime,
count(*) as numbers,
sum(amount) as amount
from customer_table customer2
where customer2.date_time > date_trunc('day', (now() - interval '1 day') - interval '1 year')
and customer2.date_time < date_trunc('day', now() - interval '1 year')
and customer2.status  = 'OK'
group by  to_char(customer2.date_time, 'MM-dd')) as subQuery on subQuery.DateTime = to_char(customer1.date_time, 'MM-dd') 
where customer1.date_time > date_trunc('day', now() - interval '1 day')
and customer1.date_time < current_date - interval '1 day' + time '23:59'
group by to_char(customer1.date_time, 'MM-dd');
```

Comment: You can probably use a simpler example.  What part of the error message do you not understand?  It seems quite clear.  All unaggregated columns (or expressions) in the `SELECT` need to be in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: 'subQuery.numbers' column is aggregated in left join part why do i need to add  'subQuery.numbers' in the GROUP BY?

Comment: Because it's not aggregated in the main select clause.

Comment: Oh thanks for the information....i thought that subquery aggregated attributs are reconize in the main as well.
Actually my query is 20 times longer than this exemple which means that i have to add 20 columns in GROUP BY ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+must+appear+in+the+GROUP+BY

Comment: I really appreciate your helps, it helped me a lot. :D
@GordonLinoff

Comment: I really appreciate your helps, it helped me a lot. :D
@simonatrcl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `subQuery.numbers` and `subQuery.amount` (they appear in the `SELECT` list) to the `GROUP BY` clause.

Otherwise, which of the several `subQuery.numbers` that belong to one `to_char(customer1.date_time, 'MM-dd')` should be used?